How do I get table data from a label object in sqlalchemy?
Lets say I have the following simplified example:
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped

class TableA(DeclarativeBase):
    col_name = Mapped[str | None]
    parent_id = Mapped[int]

class TableB(DeclarativeBase):
    col_name = Mapped[str | None]
    parent_id = Mapped[int]

class TableC(DeclarativeBase):
    col_name = Mapped[str | None]
    parent_id = Mapped[int]

MY_MAPPINGS = {
   "a__col_name" : func.coalesce(TableA.col_name, "").label("some_col_name"),
   "b__col_name" : func.coalesce(TableB.col_name, "").label("another__col_name"),
   "c__col_name" : func.coalesce(TableC.col_name, "").label("third__col_name"),
}

def get_query(mapping: str, parent_id: int):
    col = MY_MAPPINGS[mapping]
    return select(col)

That should be fine. But now what if I want to add a filter on this query for parent_id, how would I do this? Ideally I would want to do something like
.filter(col.table.parent_id = parent_id)

But col is type sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Label and col.table is None. What do I do here?

To do this we need to access the original column via the label's element's clauses attribute.
clauses lists the parts that make up the function object that has been labelled, and in this case the first such part is the original column. Note that the filter attribute must be accessed via the table's c or columns object rather than directly as with an ORM entity attribute.
col = sa.func.coalesce(MyModel.spam, '').label('eggs')
table = next(iter(col.element.clauses)).table
q = sa.select(col).where(table.c.parent_id)

